# Promoting jenkins builds in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We are using '[Promoting Builds in Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-PromotingBuildsinArtifactory)' to promote our successful builds. The promotion is performed after the build finished using a GUI.

I've noticed that after promoting a build in Jenkins, there is NO indication in jenkins that the build was promoted. Do I miss something? How can we 'mark' promoted build so in future we could find easily?

Additional question, can we run some extra actions during the Artifactory promotion? For example, we would like to promote build and send an email.

Comment: You really need to have manual intervention to promote the build ?  I am using groovy way to promote the build automatically after the build success . In groovy way you can include email sending option also.

Comment: yes, we must have man-in-the loop to approve a release

Comment: Well, we solved the issue by another jenkins job that triggered by URL change. The job listen a URL of the promoted repo and when changed runs our custom actions.